# Return `bytes` or `bytearray` when processing chunks of binary data?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, idioms

When returning/yielding chunks of binary data, is it more idiomatic to return `bytes` or `bytearray`?

My function accumulates data in a `bytearray` and currently returns `bytes(myarray)`. Are there any reasons for or against returning just 
the `bytearray` directly? In particular, if a function expects `bytes` and gets `bytearray`, are there any possible pitfalls (as long as it doesn't check the actual type)?

According to the [documentation of `bytearray`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#bytearray):

> It has most of the usual methods of mutable sequences, described in Mutable Sequence Types, as well as **most methods that the `bytes` type has**, see [Bytes and Byte Array Methods](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-methods).

(My emphasis.) This suggests that `bytearray` can be used in any place that where `bytes` is expected.

Comment: `ByteArray` got index but `bytes` haven't any idea about of index. Byte-array protect all patterns from wrong encodings, but can't use directly, need translate before usage(mean bytes(byte-array)). So short description : **`bytearray` is raw source, `bytes` are output.**

Answer (score 0):

They are not interchangeable for every possible case. Some code may use type checking and they have different types. Like their names, types are `bytearray` and `bytes`.

After question edit:

The only difference is that [bytes is an immutable version of bytearray](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#bytes).

So, `bytearray` can be used in any place where `bytes` is expected.

Comment: Note: This isn't perfect. Some APIs will perform an `isinstance(x, bytes)` check without also allowing `bytearray`. Inconsistencies [like this are usually considered a bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue34465), but it does happen.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Using `if isinstance(address, bytes):` will exclude `bytearray`. So, why `bytes`, why not `bytearray`? It does seem as a bug to me as long as `bytes` and `bytearray` both represent a bytes string. `if isinstance(address, (bytes, bytearray)):` would be correct.

Comment: I was pointing out that this was a mistake that usually gets fixed when noticed. I'm not trying to justify it. That said, even allowing `bytes`+`bytearray` is usually not broad enough; byte-width `memoryview`s, `array.array`s, and `mmap.mmap`s, among others, should all be interchangeable. In modern Python, they *finally* added [an ABC to group these, `collections.abc.ByteString`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.ByteString), but it's going to take a while for all the tests in the standard library to use it reliably.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I just did emphasize your point. Even `collections.abc.ByteString` [will just check](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/_collections_abc.py#L941) for `bytes` and `bytearray`. According to [PEP3137](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3137/#comparisons) `bytes` and `bytearray` are comparable and orderable. Also, I do agree with your points made in your second comment.

Comment: You're right. While the only registrations performed in `collections.abc` are for `bytes` and `bytearray`, and third party types are allowed and expected to register themselves as `ByteString`s when appropriate, there is a problem with most such use cases since, aside from `mmap.mmap` (which could register itself, but doesn't), most such types (`memoryview`, `array.array`, `numpy` `array` type) are too general to have them always fit `ByteString`, which leaves manual instance checks (e.g. convert to `memoryview` catching `TypeError`, check `v.c_contiguous and v.ndim == 1 and v.format == 'B'`).